# Arduino nano + microSD module + ethernet module does not assign IP address

Tags: arduino, ethernet, sd

I would like to create a small web server to enable or disable devices via ethernet connection, except that the network module and the SD reader did **not seem to work if connected simultaneously**.
That is, if I remove the SD reader the Ethernet module starts to work perfectly.

Below I leave the current version of code used for the tests:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
//#include <SD.h>
#include "SdFat.h"

SdFat SD;

#define SS_ETH 10
#define CS_microSD 9

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(SS_ETH, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS_ETH, HIGH);

  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(CS_microSD)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("initialization done.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // LOOP
}
```

output produced by the program via serial:

```
Initializing SD card...
initialization done.
server is at 255.255.255.255
```

If instead I remove the microSD from the reader and restart the circuit I get:

```
Initializing SD card...
initialization done.
server is at 0.0.0.0
```

---

**Hardware:**

- Arduino Nano
- W5100 ethernet module ( https://www.ebay.it/itm/SHIELD-MINI-W5100-modulo-ETHERNET-per-ARDUINO-ART-CV05/262454631406?hash=item3d1b83dbee:g:ltYAAOSwHsRYE0KC )
- microSD reader ( https://www.ebay.it/itm/Lettore-micro-SD-card-reader-writer-pic-arduino-raspberry-shield-ART-CL06/261625448910?hash=item3cea1789ce:g:tF0AAOSwAYtWOclu )

**Wiring diagram**

- pin 9 -> CS microSD
- pin 10 -> SS Ethernet
- pin 11 -> MOSI
- pin 12 -> MISO
- pin 13 -> SCK

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk8Xx9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Update 1:**
Thanks to the suggestions of @Juraj I tried to disconnect the MISO pin of the SD reader and the IP assignment was successful.
Furthermore the SD.h library has been replaced with SdFat.h ..

The card reader has an **LVC125A level converter** as shown in this image: https://e-radionica.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/s/dsc_1819.jpg

Also here is the LVC125A level converter datasheet: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/171748/TI/LVC125A.html

**UPDATE 2:** a hardware modification to the reader is required to solve the problem since the MISO pin remains permanently enabled.
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=360718.msg2942160#msg2942160

Comment: many SD card adapters do that. they have a logic level conversion on MISO and that disturbs the bus. but 0.0.0.0 is not a good output either. first make the ethernet work

Comment: thanks for your comment Juraj! how could the noise produced by the SD card reader be reduced?

Comment: I am not an expert of this, but in my understanding the card doesn't drive the line while it is not selected, so the converter has the 5 V side HIGH

Comment: I had already tried, but with no result .. however I did not know that SD readers disturbed the MISO communication line and right now I was looking at this discussion: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=276274.0

Comment: so you will try SdFat library? Bill Greiman mentions the level shifters problem in this comment https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=276274.msg2016819#msg2016819

Comment: Can you post the schematic of both modules and the wiring you have done? As it currently stands from your description, you are missing ground connection.

Comment: scheme added .. =)

Comment: Yes Juraj, even if I have little hope this evening I will try the SdFat library .. thanks again for the information! =)

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the SdFat library without any result.. =(

Comment: you can inspect the SD module traces to see if it has level conversion on MISO

Comment: Yes @Juraj, the **LVC125A** level converter is present ..
In the question I added the information about the level converter.. thanks for the support!

Comment: the picture doesn't show MISO trace to converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already written in the question I opened the problem was solved by performing this change to the card reader: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=360718.msg2942160#msg2942160

Micro SD readers equipped with **LVC125A** chips have the MISO output perpetually enabled and disrupting communication with other devices.

I thank one last time **@Juraj** for his support: without his advice I could never have solved my problem.
Thank you!